# Sql with custme condition in Dataikau

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

I am learning to join 2 tables  with condition in Dataiku using sql

I have started this code :

```
SELECT * 
FROM $left 
JOIN $right 
ON $left.Groupement_Cl2 == $right.Groupement_cl2
(I have no Idea for the rest)
```

I would like to add a condition saying:

if the element in $left.Groupement_Cl2 equal the elements in $right.Groupement_Cl2then join

else if the 2 first element of (in  row) equal the  2 first elements in $right.Groupement_Cl2 then join

Here is a concret example :

if in $left.Groupement_Cl2 I have 3245 and in $right.Groupement_Cl2 I have 
 3245  then join

else if in $left.Groupement_Cl2 I have 3245 but in $right.Groupement_Cl2I have only 32 then join

thanks for your helps

Comment: It is quite not clear on the idea for me... could you please told us what are the data you have in your database and what are the data that you need out of this?

Answer (score 0):

I will try it with what I understand of your question :

With an initialisation like this one, on PostgreSQL 11 :

```
create table t1 (id int primary key);
create table t2 (id int primary key, id_t1 int references t1(id));

insert into t1 values (3245), (123), (32);
insert into t2 values (1,null), (2,3245), (3,32);
```

Maybe this is the form that you want to achieve?

```
select *
from t1
    inner join t2
    on t1.id = t2.id_t1
where t1.id = 3245;
```